# big differences in mysql execution time: minimum 2 secs - maximum 120 secs

Tags: mysql, time, execution

**The Situation:** 
I use a (php) cronjob to keep my database up-to-date. the affected table contains about 40,000 records. basically, the cronjob deletes all entries and inserts them afterwards (with different values ofc). I have to do it this way, because they really ALL change, because they are all interrelated.

**The Problem:** 
Actually, everything works fine. The cronjob is doin' his job within 1.5 to 2 seconds (again, for about 40k inserts - i think this is adequate). MOSTLY.. But sometimes, the query takes up to 60, 90 or even 120 seconds!

I indexed my database. And I think query is good working, due to the fact it only needs 2 seconds mots of the time. I close the connection via mysql_close();

Do you have any ideas? If you need more information please tell me.
Thanks in advance.

**Edit:** Well, it seems like there was no problem with the inserts. it was a complex SELECT query, that made some trouble. Tho, thanks to everyone who answered!

Comment: Something have a record lock on it maybe?

Comment: are there any other cronjobs working on that table? Is it otherwise used heavily? What database engine do you use?

Comment: @Joe Meyer: sorry, but what do you mean by "record lock on it"?

Comment: @TheChaos: Well, I have another cronjob working on that table, but I set a time difference of 10 minutes. database engine: mysql MyISAM protocol 10. does this information help? do you mean that by db engine?

Comment: Enable slow query log, inspect what exactly slows it down. Don't use MyISAM, use InnoDB. Also, for scheduled operations you could use MySQL event scheduler instead of cron, so your database can be self-repairing or whatever you're doing with the cronjob.

Comment: @mindshit: Yup, meant that info: The difference can be that MyISAM does table locking while InnoDB does row level locking. So in case you change data in one script it would lock the whole table instead of the rows you are actually changing -> 2. Process has to wait to get that lock

Comment: @TheChaos: I changed the affected tables to InnoDB - the first time I executetd the cronjob it took like 100 seconds. now, it takes always something between 6 and 12 seconds. is it normal that this is a bit slower than with MyISAM? is it normal it took so long on first execution?

Comment: ok InnoDB is a bit slower with INSERTS, this explains the difference in "normal" execution time. are the indexes newly created in first execution? does this explains the long first exec time?

Answer (score 0):

[Sorry, apparently I haven't mastered the formatting yet]

From what I read, I can conclude that your cronjob is using bulk-insert statements. If you know when cronjob works, I suggest you to start a Database Engine Tuning Advisor session and see what other processes are running while the cronjob do its things. A bulk-insert has some restrictions with the number of fields and the number of rows at once. You could read the subtitles of this msdn http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx

> Performance Considerations
>
> If the number of pages to be flushed in a
>   single batch exceeds an internal threshold, a full scan of the buffer
>   pool might occur to identify which pages to flush when the  batch
>   commits. This full scan can hurt bulk-import performance. A likely
>   case of exceeding  the   internal threshold occurs when a large buffer
>   pool is combined with a slow I/O subsystem.   To avoid buffer
>   overflows on large machines, either do not use the TABLOCK hint (which
>   will   remove the bulk optimizations) or use a smaller batch size
>   (which preserves the bulk   optimizations). Because computers vary, we
>   recommend that you test various batch sizes with your data load to
>   find out what works best for you.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! But I only have access to the database via phpMyAdmin, so I dont think I can do that, can I?

Comment: Ah yes! I just noticed you tagged MySQL and not SQL. Haven't had my first coffee yet. Can you tell me what your cronjob does? Is it using the infile command?

Comment: No, it's not using the infile command (as far as I know ;)). As i described above: the cronjob does the following: 1. DELETE FROM abc WHERE bcd=efg 2. INSERT INTO abc (a, b, c) VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4,5,6),... this is it basically. additionally there is another select query at first. i need it to generate the new entries

Comment: Very well. I would strongly recommend to modify the job so that is uses infile command. That is the equivalent to bulk-insert or BCP in SQL. You should see a great performance improvement.

Comment: Mhh, did I get it right? I should use "LOAD DATA INFILE" to insert the data into the database instead of INSERT INTO? So a possible way would be to generate a .txt and "load it into the datatable" via LOAD DATA INFILE, right?

Comment: Absolutely! Insert into will only be efficient when inserting several lines. With 40k records, you are better off with a bulk insert aka load data infile.